# Does 9'-11" mean any length less than 9 feet and 11 inches?

Tags: building-regulations

This post gives a [deck joist span table](https://www.decks.com/how-to/41/deck-joist-sizing-and-spacing)

[image]

Does 9'-11" mean any length less than 9 feet and 11 inches?

Comment: 2x6 pine joists spaced 12” apart on center can span up to 9’11”

Comment: Yes it does mean anything less than 9'-11" , including 9'-11"

Answer (score 1):

I think that table should say "Maximum allowable span" , so yes anything up-to  9'11" is allowable.

Comment: That’s what I understand as “allowable span” ie that but no more... maximum is not needed.

Comment: You might find someone suggesting your answer is too short soon - it’s fine forme though, clear and succinct.